# find the smallest interval in which the eigen value of the matrix lie

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 5 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
  $$

I was practicing questions on Matrices & Determinants and was going well with the topic until this question! shows up.

I have no idea on how to solve this question.

This problem is taking a lot of my mind and I am not able to go forward while this problem is still stuck in my mind.

Please Help!!

Thank You

Comment: Clearly marwalix's answer is correct, but might be somehow difficult to solve explicitly. For a general formal answer use the fact that $\lambda_{\min / \max}=\min / \max_{|x|=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle$ where $\lambda_{\min / \max}$ stands for the smallest/biggest eigenvalue. Then the interval may be formally be written as $[\lambda_{\min},\lambda_{\max}]$

Comment: @b00nheT 
Can you please explain.

Comment: I'm just saying that to find the smallest/greatest eigenvalue you can compute the minimum/maximum of the above function $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ with the boundary condition $|x|=1$. Then your interval is clearly given by these two lower and upper bounds.
But I'm also claiming this method to be somewhat formal: i.e. in general (for low dimensional cases) it's easier to just compute the roots of the characteristic polynomial as shown in the below answer.

Answer (score 2):

Compute $\operatorname{det}(A-X\cdot Id)$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$. One should find

$$-X^3+11X^2-27X+17$$

The roots of this polynomial in ascending order are $1$, $5-2\sqrt{2}$ and $5+2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: In ascending order???

Comment: Yes $1\le 5-2\sqrt{2}\le 5+2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Sorry, I misread the answers as $\sqrt 5\pm2\sqrt 2$, so that one of them was negative.:o(. I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is symmetric, the eigenvalues are real. They are in the union of the intervals (why?)  $[3-4,3+4],[5-4,5+4],[3-4,3+4]$, that is in the interval $[-1,9]$. If you want exactly the smallest interval, then, of course, you must calculate (all !) the eigenvalues and I do not see any interest to your question.